# Django - Filtering objects using ajax post call data returns nothing

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have the following Ajax POST call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'meds:prescription' %}",
    data: {selected:'selected' , csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
    success: function(result) {
        window.location = "{% url 'meds:prescription' %}";
    }
});
```

Where selected is an array of ids for example `[5, 9, 17]`

And the following view:

```
class PrescriptionView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'meds/prescription.html'
    context_object_name = 'meds'
    model = Medicament

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        selected_ids = self.request.POST.getlist('selected[]')
        meds = self.get_queryset().filter(id__in=selected_ids)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'meds': meds})

    def get_queryset(self):
        ids = self.request.POST.getlist('selected[]')
        return Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ids = self.request.POST.getlist('selected[]')
        context = super(PrescriptionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'meds': Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=ids),
            'date': datetime.now()
        })
        return context
```

What I'm trying to do is just to be redirected to the prescription template with the objects filtered using the data from the post call, but instead my template is just empty, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: Firstly, you seem to be sending a string, `"selected"`, not an array. Secondly, in the view you are trying to get the value of `selected[]` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a string `selected:'selected'` not an array. Remove single quotes around `selected` in your ajax handler:

```
data: {selected:'selected' , csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
```

should be:

```
data: {selected: selected, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
```

Comment: I have tried that as well and it doesnt seem to work either, no results!

Comment: Have you also tried to change `self.request.POST.getlist('selected[]')` with `self.request.POST.getlist('selected')`??

Comment: Looking back at your code, you have some serious flaws in your code. Why you are doing a refresh on `success` of ajax call `window.location = "{% url 'meds:prescription' %}";`? Why you are not sending back JSON response from your view?

Comment: yes I have tried that as well. I'm redirecting on success because I would like to have the data to be shown in a different page than the one I'm sending data from

Comment: I don't know how you want to achieve that, your POST data will be lost on refresh.

Comment: Even if the same view that handles the POST call is the same one that renders the template to where I refresh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141735/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-mariam).